# I'm getting a Error on creating orders inside the Admin panel Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, error, sales-order

I'm getting a error on creating the order inside the Admin panel like below

> Order saving error: Your API key is not valid.

I don't known why it is happening.??

Please anyone help me. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using any custom modules?

Comment: yes onestep checkout..

Comment: I'm guessing they require some kind of configuration that uses an api key? Other than that, what payment method are you trying to use? I'm looking at code now to hunt down what might cause that error.

Answer (score 0):

The only places I can find that throw exception with that text **Order saving error: %1** are:

#### Magento_Authorizenet

In: vendor/magento/module-authorizenet/Controller/Adminhtml/Authorizenet/Directpost/Payment/Place.php

On line 128:

```
...
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('Order saving error: %1', $e->getMessage()));
    $isError = true;
}
...
```

#### Magento_Sales

In: vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Save.php

On line 74:

```
...
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Order saving error: %1', $e->getMessage()));
    $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/*/');
}
...
```

---

If you aren't using **Authorizenet** as the payment method, then we can probably assume it's not coming from that.

I don't see any occurrences of **Your API key is not valid** at all in the codebase so it must be a response from a remote service. Closest match I'm seeing is in the **Magento_Signifyd** module. Maybe check to see if that service is enabled. It's settings can be found under *Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Fraud Protection*

Comment: im used Cash on delivery and free delivery option , still this issue not going :(

Answer (score 0):

Your can follow below step to fix that issue.

Step 1) You can check your third party module as you are using in your store.

Step 2) After your confirmation of module. you can check in magento admin any    of the module have used api key.

Step 3) Try to implement that API key as correct to fix issue.

Hope this step you have helpful.